# ACF pro Map in Laravel(blade)

Tags: laravel, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to show the ACF repeater for google map with multiple markers, I already added all the code and follow all the steps from [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/):

the problem is the map is not zoom and i guess the Lat and Lng are not working.

```html
@if( have_rows('google_map_repeater', '745')  )
        <div class="acf-map">
        @while ( have_rows('google_map_repeater', '745') ) @php(the_row())
           @php( $location = get_sub_field('location'))
                    <div class="marker" data-lat="{{ $location['lat'] }}" data-lng="{{ $location['lng'] }}" >
                            <h4>{{ the_sub_field('title') }}</h4>
                            <p class="address">{{ $location['address'] }}</p>
                    </div>
        @endwhile
     </div> 
@endif
```

Comment: where are you ending @endphp in your markup?

Comment: I'm adding the code to the part of of my blade template on the backend.